# Why does a messed up character print(C)?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I'm writing a `strovr` function, which finds all the intersections of two strings. For some reason, it occasionally prints mangled characters when dealing with a 1 character long intersection.

For example, with the strings `Hey Brother` and `Hey Bro`, it produces:

```
Bro
He
o
rL?z?//MANGLED
e
```

I assume it has to do with a pointer/memory issue.

Here is my code.

```c
#import <stdio.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <string.h>

char **strovr(char c1[], char cmp[], int *len_response)
{
    int lenc1 = strlen(c1), lencmp = strlen(cmp);
    int len_big = lenc1 > lencmp ? lenc1 : lencmp;
    int len_small = lenc1 < lencmp ? lenc1 : lencmp;
    char **both[2] = {&c1, &cmp};
    char **returned = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
    int size_returned = 0;
    int indlonger = lenc1 > lencmp ? 0 : 1, indshorter = !indlonger, i = len_small;
    char A, B;

    while (i >=(0-len_big))
    {
        int i_incr = i >= 0 ? i : 0;
        int j      = i >= 0 ? 0 : 0-i;
        int until  = i >= 0 ? len_small : i +len_big;
        char A = (*both[indshorter])[i_incr];
        B = (*both[indlonger])[j];

        int currently_in = 0;
        int ind_begin;

        while (i_incr <until)
        {

            if (B==A && B!=32 && A!=32)
            {
                if (!currently_in)
                {
                    ind_begin = j;
                    currently_in = 1;
                }

                if (((*both[indshorter])[i_incr+1] != (*both[indlonger])[j+1]) || (i_incr+1 == len_small) )
                {
                    currently_in = 0;
                    int ind_end = j;
                    char *match = malloc(sizeof(char) * (ind_end-ind_begin));
                    if (match != NULL )   //DIAGNOSIS SHOULD START HERE.
                    {
                        int curr_ind = 0;
                        if (ind_end-ind_begin > 0)
                        {
                            for (int c = ind_begin; c<=ind_end; c++)
                            {
                                match[curr_ind] = (*both[indlonger])[c];
                                curr_ind++;
                            }
                            //                            printf("%s ",match);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            match[0] = A;
                            //                            match[1] = "c";
                            printf("%s: STRLEN(%lu)\n",match,strlen(match));
                        }

                        if (size_returned == 0) {}
                        else returned = realloc(returned, sizeof(char*)*(size_returned+1));

                        if (match == NULL)
                        {
                            printf("\nError::Return string not properly initialized\n");
                            exit(1);
                        }

                        returned[size_returned] = match;
                        size_returned++;
                    }
                }

            }

            i_incr++;
            j++;
            A = (*both[indshorter])[i_incr];
            B = (*both[indlonger])[j];
        }
        i--;
    }
    *len_response = size_returned;
    return returned;
}


int main()
{
    int resp;
    char **intersections = strovr("Hey Brother", "Hello Bro",&resp);

    printf("\nThe intersection of Hey Brother and Hello Bro is:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < resp; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(intersections[i]); j++)
        {
            printf("%c",intersections[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that c? what is the `import` thing? Also, do not type your code in the site's editor, copy it and paste it from your working copy because you might miss to type in the problem when typing...

Comment: I've got a working solution at https://gist.github.com/aclinnovator/204de5da7099f6bfcbb3

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in c are indexed from `0` so this

```
malloc(sizeof(char) * (ind_end-ind_begin));
```

combined with this

```
for (int c = ind_begin; c<=ind_end; c++)
```

is the problem, because once `c == ind_end` you invoke undefined behavior, and if `ind_begin != 0` you will have many more chances of strange things happening.

I also assume that you aren't allocating space for the terminating `'\0'`, every string in c requires `N + 1` bytes to be sotred, the `N` characters + a special sentinel value `'\0'`, functions like `strlen()` expect this value there.

Your code also has a lot of potential undefined behavior, because you never check pointers for `NULL` before passing them to functions that will not check like `strlen()`.

Your `realloc()` is also wrong, and you don't check if it returned `NULL`, which I don't think it did, but you must check, a safe way to call `realloc()` is this

```
void *dontOverwriteOldPointer;
dontOverwriteOldPointer = realloc(oldPointer, newSize); 
if (dontOverwriteOldPointer == NULL) 
 {
    free(oldPointer);
    return goodThatWeDid_not_OverwriteTheOldPointer_ReturnErrorValue();
 }
oldPointer = dontOverwriteOldPointer;
```

Another common mistake is this

```
for (int j = 0; j < strlen(intersections[i]); j++)
/*                    ^ not good */
```

you should not call `strlen()` like that because the string length is not stored anywhere, so `strlen()` computes the length on each iteration, and hence your program's performance will be affected, you should store the value like this

```
size_t length = strlen(intersections[i]);
for (int j = 0 ; j < length ; j++)
```

and you don't even need that, it's all about understanding the `'\0'` thing, you can do this

```
for (int j = 0 ; intersections[i][j] != '\0' ; j++)
    printf("%c", intersections[i][j]);
```

and that is precisely why `strlen()` would cause undefined behavior if there is no `'\0'` at the end of the array, as will `printf("%s", someString);`.